# Join two tables by not unique attribute in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am new in laravel and php and I want to retrieve value depends on three tables, I use this code to retrieve from the first table

```
 $jobid=$request->input('jobID');
    $coursenum=$request->input('referenceNumber');
    $semester=$request->input('semester');
    $checklogin=DB::table('members')->select('externalPersonKey')->where(['jobID'=>$jobid])->first();                        
 $extrnal1=$checklogin->externalPersonKey;
```

now I will use the information from the first table to check the value is exist in **members_courses_assign** table then join it with **course** table .

note: 
(**referenceNumber**) is not unique so I must write it with (**termkey**) in the condition

```
    $referenceNumber1=DB::table('members_courses_assign')->select('referenceNumber','termkey')->join('courses','members_courses_assign.referenceNumber','=','courses.referenceNumber')->where(['externalPersonKey'=>$extrnal1,'termkey'=>$semester,'referenceNumber'=>$coursenum])->get();
```

i have this error:

> QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052
>   Column 'referenceNumber' in field list is ambiguous

and I try another way:

```
$referenceNumber1=DB::table('members_courses_assign')->select('referenceNumber','termkey')->where(['externalPersonKey'=>$extrnal1,'termkey'=>$semester,'referenceNumber'=>$coursenum])->first();
    $refrence1= $referenceNumber1->referenceNumber;
    $termkey3=$referenceNumber1->termkey;
    $infocourse=DB::table('courses')->select('enname','class')->where(['referenceNumber'=>$refrence1,'termkey'=>$termkey3])->first();
```

and have this error:

> ErrorException Object of class stdClass could not be converted to
>   string

Comment: `select("referenceNumber"...` should be `select("tablename.referenceNumber"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use unique column names, i.e. `tablename.referencenumber`, not just `referencenumber` and so on.